# pyspark - making a new column lookup_l that contains a list and its elements are values from other columns from same df from current row

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas, pyspark-schema

All values are strings:

| first_name_l | first_name_r | last_name_l | last_name_r | dob_l | dob_r | city_l | city_r | average_score | matched_columns | lookup_l_list | lookup_r_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| robert | robert | null | allen | 1971-06-24 | 1971-05-24 | null | null | 49.57 | [first_name_score, dob_score] | [first_name_l, dob_l] | [first_name_r, dob_r] |
| null | robert | allen | alen | 1971-06-24 | 1971-06-24 | london | lonon | 69.95 | [dob_score, city_score, last_name_score] | [dob_l, city_l, last_name_l] | [dob_r, city_r, last_name_r] |

How to get another column named 'lookup_l' for first row that has value =[robert,1971-06-24] (values are derived from the df but column names are checked from column lookup_l_list of first row and then values are also written in same sequence as column names in lookup_l_list ) and 'lookup_r' must have value = [robert,1971-05-24] (values are derived from the df but column names are checked from column lookup_r_list of first row). Same should be done with other rows also. How to code it using pyspark. I have tried different approaches but getting error every time.

Expecting a df with all previous column and two new columns named 'lookup_l' and 'lookup_r' with expected values (list of values from other columns).

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
columns_to_concat = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
new_df = df.withColumn("new_array_column", F.array(columns_to_concat))
```